# How to call a multi-threaded C function in Cython?

Tags: python, multithreading, cython, gil

I have a question about how to call a multi-threaded C function in Cython.

Do I need to release/acquire the GIL before/after I do the multi-threaded stuff in the C function?

Or can I just use it like a normal C function?

Should I follow the directions [here](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) for general Python extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have looked down a few sections.

http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads